# Error When Calling Data From SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, fat-free-framework

I build web app with F3 and SQL Server 2005 (may have expired, hehe). When I running it from my local server (Windows / DB connection use mssql), it runs normally and may be without any problems.
But, when I running it from real server (Ubuntu / DB connection use dblib), I got the error (like picture below).
In the same server (another web app), I also using dblib to build connection from web app to database (SQL Server) and it runs normally.

Can anyone explain to me, what's the cause of the error?

[image]

Comment: You can use sql server Profiler to catch an error

Comment: I think this is related to https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues/816

Comment: @xfra35, I've read it and I try to use odbc connection, but the following error appears : **PDO::getAttribute(): SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support that attribute.**

Comment: Well the odbc driver doesn't seem to be a better choice. See https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues/982. Can't you use the `pdo_sqlsrv` driver instead? If not, I guess you're using the recent [exist()](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/commit/aa290c444698787b027274376630db67b7b01a69) method, which obviously doesn't support odbc driver, so you could try [filing an issue](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/issues) and see if something can be done at the framework level.

Comment: Thank's for your advices, maybe I will slightly change the application workflow

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error. Check your code for any spaces that are not allowed.